# Polymer-1.0 Chrome broke for datalist that is too long

Tags: html, google-chrome, datalist, polymer-1.0

I have a simple datalist with HTML5 and Polymer dom-repeat:

```
<datalist id="{{queryTitle}}">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{recommendations}}">
    <option value="{{item}}">
  </template>
</datalist>
```

I populate this datalist with an array of `recommendations` that have about 200-500 items. When I load this page and open the dropdown menu of that datalist, I got the following message from windows:

[image: Error message]

The running program that wasn't compatible was Google Chrome. The datalist still popups as usual, but the color scheme always changed to Windows 7 Basic and I really don't want this to happen.

Comment: Chrome's datalist support is crap. It just renders the list straight off your screen without providing a scroll bar. If the list is too long it crashes Desktop Window Manager on Windows. It only provided results that start with, rather than contains the text that was typed. It's completely unusable as far as I am concerned. Mozilla's behavior is exactly what any sane individual would expect. There are several bug reports open for these issues, but don't hold your breath.